# Synchronized method in java does not work as indended

Tags: java, synchronized

I want to learn how to use the synchronized method in java and implemented the following code.

```
public class checkThread {
    volatile int i = 0;
    
    public void increment() {
        i++;
    }
}
public class TestSync extends checkThread{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        checkThread ct1 = new checkThread();
        Object iLock = new Object();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
            extracted(ct1, iLock);      
        }
    }    
    private static void extracted(checkThread ct1, Object iLock) {
        synchronized (iLock) {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for(int a = 0; a < 1000; a++) {
                        ct1.increment();
                    }
                }
            });
            t1.start();
        }
        synchronized (iLock) {
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for(int a = 0; a < 1000; a++) {
                        ct1.increment();
                    }
                }
            });
            t2.start();
        }
        synchronized (iLock) {
            System.out.println(ct1.i);
        }
    }
}
```

However the output I get is not at all synchronized!

> 1000
> 2000
> 4000
> 6000
> 8000
> 9000
> 11575
> 13575
> 15575
> 17459

Why am I getting such an output and not the desired value of i in the multiples of 1000?

Comment: You are STARTING the threads in the locks, so they START asynchronously. But once they run, only the `volatile` keyword of checkThread.i prevents lost updates.
But after your code has started the Threads, it then runs the output, and possibly while the threads are still working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to make sure that the `run()` method will be completed by one thread before the other one start; then you need to synchronize the content inside the run method, not the thread creation part.

In your specific example, you need to have an object that can be accessed by both the threads, and then acquire the lock of that object.

Let me add an example below by changing your code; but this may not be the best way; just trying to explain the point.

```
checkThread iLock = new checkThread();

public void someMethod() {

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (iLock) {            
                for(int a = 0; a < 1000; a++) {
                    ct1.increment();
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();
    }

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (iLock) {            
                for(int a = 0; a < 1000; a++) {
                    ct1.increment();
                }
            }
        });
        t2.start();
    }
    
    synchronized (iLock) {
        System.out.println(ct1.i);
    }
}
```

Comment: The key thing here is that `synchronized (lock) { ... }` acquires lock after the current call stack frame starts and releases it before the current call stack frame ends.

Thread.start creates a whole new call stack (each thread gets its own stack), so the stuff in the run does not clearly relate to when the lock is acquired/released in any way.  The visual nesting of `{...}`s is deceptive here.

Comment: I understand, so I needed to include synchronized INSIDE the run block of the thread, otherwise the synchronize method does not work as intended. So if I want to start operations on the same object of the class on multiple threads, then I should always use synchronize for the code block operating on the object, not on the thread creation itself. If however, I were required to make it work by synchronizing thread creation, how might I go about doing that? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Threads are used to execute tasks in parallel, so even if you synchronize the thread creation, it will not have much impact the thread execution. Thread's execution happens inside the `run()` method.